# Function totally monotone

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ a function $2n$ differentiable with domain $]0;\infty[$ and codomain $]0;\infty[$ and $n$ a natural number with the condition :
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}f^{(k)}(x)\geq f(x)^{2n}$$

Prove that we have :$$\frac{f^{(k)}}{f^{(k+1)}}< 0$$

for $k$ an integer with $k\in [1;2n]$

And

$$(-1)^kf^{(k)}>0$$ for $k \in \pmb{\mathbb{N}}$

Furthermore we have this characterization for completely monotone (CM) function :

The following three assertions are equivalent:

(a)$\psi$ is completely monotone on$(0,∞)$(respectively on$[0,∞)$);

(b)$\psi$ is represented as the Laplace transform of a unique Radon (respectively finite) measure $ν$ on $[0 , ∞ )$ : $\psi(\lambda) = \int_{[0 , ∞ )}  e^{−λx} ν (d x ) ,  λ > 0$ (respectively $\lambda ≥ 0$ ) ;

(c) $\psi$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0 , ∞ )$ (respectively continuous on $[0 , ∞ )$ , infinitely differentiable on $(0 , ∞ )$ ) and satisfies $( − 1)^ n \psi ( n ) ≥ 0$ for every $n \in \pmb{\mathbb{N}}_0$

And finally :

Let $\psi$ : $[0 , ∞ ) → [0 , ∞ )$ be a bounded function.  Then, $\psi$ is completely monotone if and only if this conditions hold:

(a)  the function $\psi$ has an holomorphic extension on $Re ( z ) > 0$ and remains bounded there;

There is some properties on CM [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.0900.pdf)

Edit:I realize that it was too difficult like this so I create a simple exercize :

Here the initial condition is $f'+f''\geq f^2$

1)Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are solution of the initial condition with $f>g$ then we have a new solution wich is $f-g$

2)Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(x)$ is convex

3)Deduce that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for all $x>0$

4)Prove that if $f(x)$ is a solution of the initial condition so $f''(x+M)$ is also a solution with $M\geq 0$ a real number

5)Deduce that we have $(-1)^kf^{(k)}>0$ with $k \in \pmb{\mathbb{N}}$

6):Prove that we have $f(x)^{2n}<\sum_{k=0}^{n}(f^{(2k)}(x))^2<\sum_{k=1}^{2n}f^{(k)}(x)$ with $k \in \pmb{\mathbb{N}}$

7)Thanks.

Comment: what does totally monotone mean?

Comment: @zhw: he provides the definition.

Comment: @zhw. It means it's one of those really drab functions, without any colors.

Comment: how many $n$'s are there in the statement of the problem ? You wrote "$f$ is $2n$ differentiable" and then considered another $n$ ?

Comment: How do you know this is provable? Is this an exercise?

Comment: It's not an exercise it's a conjecture about function completely monotone .I try so many examples (with a software) about this ,and I didn't find any counter-examples so I think (maybe) it's true .Furthermore I discover the following property if $f$ and $g$ are solutions of the initial condition and $f-g>0$ then $f-g$ is also a solution .It lifts(raises) the idea of a maximal solution (?).

Comment: See [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/Annals/152_3/kozlovsk.pdf)

Comment: And for further informations see [here](https://www.math.uri.edu/~bonifant/cymaps-z.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443276/maximum-value-of-a-function-with-condition).The fact that the conjecture is true is real but it's very hard to prove .There is a link with the Schwarzian derivative ,function completely mononotone and Liénard équation . So maybe you could find your solution in this way .

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am leaving this answer up, but I now know that it is wrong.

---

The answer to your conjecture is actually no. That is - there exists functions $f \colon (0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ that satisfy $f' + f'' \geq f^2$, yet are strictly increasing.

As an example, take the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{2x}(\frac{2\alpha}{1 + x^{\alpha}} - \alpha - 1)$ where $\alpha = i\sqrt3$. Interestingly this function is defined in terms of complex numbers, yet you can prove that $g$ maps $(0,+\infty)$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

The only thing missing is that $g$ maps into $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $(0,+\infty)$, however it can be shown that $g(2) > 0$ and $g$ is strictly increasing.

Therefore define $h \colon (0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ via $h(x) = g(x+2)$. Though I won't do it here, you can prove that $h' + h'' \geq h^2$ with $h$ strictly increasing.

---

As a side note, if you restrict your domain from $(0,+\infty)$ to $(0,r)$ for some positive real number, then there is an even simpler example of $t(x) = s \tan(s x)$ where $s = \frac{\pi}{2r}$. Then we have $t'(x) = t^2(x) + r^2$ and $t''(x) > 0$.

Comment: I think you are wrong because it's prove that the function vanishes at infinity and the value of $x$ are real . See [here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,1513278,page=2) If you can read in french $6^{th}$ message

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that completely. Your conjecture is probably correct, though I am not sure how to prove it.